# How static content is handled in an asp.net application?

Tags: iis, asp.net, windows, static-content

I have a website that i use as a "content server" for *other* websites
So, the home page, an asp.net cms, receives 25 visits/month, while the /static/ folder receives hundreds of requests/minute 24/7
Will the asp.net application be loaded forever in the app-pool, or, since only the /static/ is accessed, the asp.net code is not loaded in the app-pool?
Because it would be a little bit waste of ram to have it loaded forever to show just to the 3 users interested it in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your shutdown idle settings for the Application Pool.  Checkout this TechNet article for instructions on how to configure this setting.  This way you can sleep easy knowing your application pool only lives for short times.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776532(WS.10).aspx

Comment: If i set the idle to a reasonable value (not the 1800 minutes default value), that means if nobody will access the asp.net program, it will shutdown, but accesses to the /static/ folder (only plain images with a leech control by ionic rewrite), won't "reset" the idle counter of the app, right?

Comment: That is correct, unless the static folder is setup as a virtual and has an application assigned to it.